# fork: retry: No child processes

Tags: centos7

today i tried to login via ssh on a centos server. Immediatly i got:

```
fork: retry: No child processes
```

but i get login. Every command i run i got the same message.

I searched google. There are many articels about not enough memory.

I run top:

```
top - 08:22:45 up 254 days, 22:34,  1 user,  load average: 0.02, 0.07, 0.06
Tasks: 215 total,   1 running, 214 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 23.0/32779576 [|||||||||||||||||||||||                                                                             ]
KiB Swap:  0.0/0        [                                                                                                    ]
```

i run df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G  1.6G   15G  11% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       400G  260G  141G  65% /
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/10001
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/995
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/987
```

There is enough ram and disk space. What can i check?

Thanks for your help.

Edit: If i login via ssh using another user there is no error! It seems there is only one user affected. I am running plesk on the server.